# How to fetch entities with multiple parameters with Spring and JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Lets say I have a site on which the user can select multiple variations of parameters.
I can write what I need in SQL, but the problem is that there might be a lot of OR(a lot of multi-value parameters):

```
SELECT * FROM vacancy JOIN types t on vacancy.id = t.id  
WHERE (company ='Luxoft' OR company LIKE '%SoftServe%' OR...)  
AND (location LIKE 'Kiev' OR location LIKE 'Lviv' OR..)  
AND (type like 'Java' OR type like 'JavaScript' OR..)
```

Right now I'm doing it by fetching all vacancies from my database, iterating through all of them, saving those that contains needed TITLE, then I am iterate from this newly saved vacancies and find those that have one of the needed company parameters, location parameters an type parameters.
But because now I have multi-type vacancies that are mapped to vacancy database by `@ElementCollection` and `@CollectionTable` fetching of types become very slow.
I thought about Spring ExampleMatcher but I'm not sure that it can do this.
Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to be understandable and write codes in code style not normal text style, take a look at help center to learn how to ask questions.

Comment: That's what criteria queries or QueryDSL are for: dynamically generate queries.

Comment: Relevant documentation: [Spring Data JPA - Querydsl Extension](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<EntityName> c = cb.createQuery(EntityName.class);
    Root<EntityName> root = c.from(EntityName.class);


    Predicate company = cb.or ( 
        cb.equal(root.<String>get("company"), "Luxoft"),
        cb.like(root.<String>get("name"), "%SoftServe%"));

    Predicate location = cb.or ( 
        cb.equal(root.<String>get("location"), "Kiev"),
        cb.like(root.<String>get("location"), "%Lviv%"));

    Expression<String> typeExpression = root.get("type");

    Predicate type = typeExpression.in("Java", "Javascript");

    c.where(company, location, type);

    return c.getResultList();
```

`CriteriaBuilder` and `CriteriaQuery` classes of Hibernate will help you to create such queries with the code.